# Finding users in a XML-file and return in a variable

Tags: bash

The problem I am facing appears to be too complicated for me. Therefore I hope in getting help here as of being my last chance.

The company of my client is using a huge XML file containing test departments including users of those test departments and more. An extract of a department called "Fighters" would look as following (copied 1:1 (but with different names and numbers)):

```
<department name="/fighters" id="123879" group="channel" case="none" use="no">
   <options index_name="index.html" listing="0" sum="no"  allowed="no" />
   <target prefix="ttp" suffix=".net" />
   <type="effort">
    <region="20491" readonly="fs1a" readwrite="fs1a" upload="yes" download="yes" repl="yes" hard="0" soft"0" prio="0" write="no" stage="yes" migrate="no" size="0" >
     <read="content" readwrite="content" hard="215822106624" soft="237296943104" prio="5" write="yes"  stage="yes" migrate="no" size="0" />
     <overflow name="20491-set-writable" />
    </replicate>
    <region="20576" readonly="fs1a" readwrite="fs1a" upload="yes" download="yes" repl="yes" hard="0" soft"0" prio="0" write="no" stage="yes" migrate="no" size="0" >
     <read="content" readwrite="content" hard="215822106624" soft="237296943104" prio="5" write="yes"  stage="yes" migrate="no" size="0" />
     <overflow name="20576-set-writable" />
    </replicate>
   </replication>
   <user="T:106603" />
   <user="T:123879" />
   <user="test" />
   <user="ele::123456" />
   <user="company-temp" />
   <user="companymw2" />
   <user="bird" />
   <user="coding11" />
   <user="plazamedia" />
   <allow go="123456=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />
```

Each test department is facing an unique id (here `123879`). The users can have nicknames (like `coding11`) or are real ones (like `bird`).

So I want to get all users - but not user "test" (which appears to be there all times) - stored in an variable (likely setup as array) by just searching for the department-id. How would the command look like in detail?

Note: The number of users in a department and the regions vary.

Comment: Your `xml` is not well-formed.

Comment: True, but this should not harm.

Comment: Yes. It harms, because you cannot use a `xml` parser to solve it. And that's the way to go.

Comment: I answered this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chance with `bash scripting`:

```
awk -F'"' '/<user=/{ print $2 }' input.xml
```

(OR)

```
sed -e '/^<user/!{d}' -e '/^<user/s/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/' input.xml
```

**Your xml file is not correct formatted but TOTALY**
Why don't use python for such tasks?

This is fast and accurate...
You can try:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import commands
input = sys.argv[1]
output = sys.argv[2]

tree = ET.parse(input)
root = tree.getroot()

for <something> in root.findall('<Start From Here>'):
.
.
.
```